# bind datagrid to collection of custom objects in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a collection say `NotificationHistoryCollection` which is a collection of `NotificationHistory` objects which in turn has `NotificationDetails` object and collection of `NotificationHistoryDetail`. How do I bind `NotificationDetails` to a datagrid and `NotificationHistoryDetail` collection to another datagrid in silverlight 4.0

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea:

```
 public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        friends.Add(new Friend(){Name = "Pappu",Email = new EmailAddress(){Email = "test@test.com"}});
        dgFriends.ItemsSource = Friends;
    }

    ObservableCollection<Friend> friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>();
    public ObservableCollection<Friend> Friends { get { return friends; } set { friends = value; } }
}

public class Friend
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EmailAddress Email { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

 <data:DataGrid x:Name="dgFriends" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Email.Email}" Header="EmailAddress" IsReadOnly="True"></data:DataGridTextColumn>               
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
```

Result:
[image]